# XPS 2720 is not giving 1440p resolution in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I got an old XPS 2720 (All in One desktop) with 4th gen i7, 8gb ram, QHD screen, nvidia 750M. Now I installed only ubuntu 18.04 (no Windows, no dual boot required). The problem is that I am only getting upto 1920x1080 resolution using either out of the box intel driver or nvidia 390 driver, no qhd resolution. I do not find any option to change resolution in the NVIDIA X-Server settings.

This is very frustrating because from the recovery mode of ubuntu I am getting the qhd resolution (with native intel graphics), not in the normal boot.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't [cross post](https://superuser.com/q/1478292/398021).

Comment: All in one, desktop, or laptop? There are three Dell XPS 2720s. Please click [edit] and advise which you have. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, do [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot search I think the problem is still with the graphics driver. However, I found a temporary solution. `cvt` somehow shows incorrect result (modeline) for 2k resolution on this particular computer (XPS 2720 all in one). After reading [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399525) I used the following commands (both on terminal and in the ~/.profile file)

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1442 1447 1481 +hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-2 2560x1440_60
```

Here the modeline is different than what `cvt 2560 1440` shows.
If you are on Dell XPS 2720 I am pretty sure this trick will give you a temporary fix.